# octomap_msgs/conversions.h: No such file or directory

Tags: ros, octomap, ros-humble, colcon

Using 64-bit Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
On "colcon build" I'm recieving the following error:

```
/home/ajifoster3/dev_ws/src/octomap_publisher/src/octomap_publisher_node.cpp:2:10: fatal error: octomap_msgs/conversions.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <octomap_msgs/conversions.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/octomap_publisher_node.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/octomap_publisher_node.dir/src/octomap_publisher_node.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:137: CMakeFiles/octomap_publisher_node.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:146: all] Error 2
---
Failed   <<< octomap_publisher [0.17s, exited with code 2]
```

---

opt/ros/humble/include/octomap_msgs has a file called conversions.h

My ros node:

```
#include <octomap/OcTree.h>
#include <octomap_msgs/conversions.h>
#include <rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp>

class OctomapPublisher : public rclcpp::Node {
public:
    OctomapPublisher() : Node("octomap_publisher") {
        this->declare_parameter<std::string>("octomap_file", "/home/ajifoster3/occupancy_map_full.txt");
        std::string octomap_file;
        this->get_parameter("octomap_file", octomap_file);

        auto tree = std::make_shared<octomap::OcTree>(octomap_file);
        octomap_msgs::msg::Octomap octomap_msg;
        octomap_msgs::binaryMapToMsg(*tree, octomap_msg);

        publisher_ = this->create_publisher<octomap_msgs::msg::Octomap>("octomap", 1);
        timer_ = this->create_wall_timer(
            std::chrono::milliseconds(1000),
            [this, octomap_msg]() {
                publisher_->publish(octomap_msg);
            });
    }

private:
    rclcpp::Publisher<octomap_msgs::msg::Octomap>::SharedPtr publisher_;
    rclcpp::TimerBase::SharedPtr timer_;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
    rclcpp::spin(std::make_shared<OctomapPublisher>());
    rclcpp::shutdown();
    return 0;
}
```

my CMakeLists.txt is the following

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(octomap_publisher)

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
find_package(octomap_msgs REQUIRED)

add_executable(octomap_publisher_node src/octomap_publisher_node.cpp)

ament_target_dependencies(octomap_publisher_node rclcpp octomap_msgs)

install(TARGETS
  octomap_publisher_node
  DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME}
)

if(BUILD_TESTING)
  find_package(ament_lint_auto REQUIRED)
  ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies()
endif()

ament_package()
```

package.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://download.ros.org/schema/package_format3.xsd" schematypens="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"?>
<package format="3">
  <name>octomap_publisher</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>TODO: Package description</description>
  <maintainer email="ajifoster3@gmail.com">ajifoster3</maintainer>
  <license>TODO: License declaration</license>

  <buildtool_depend>ament_cmake</buildtool_depend>

  <depend>rclcpp</depend>
  <depend>octomap_msgs</depend>

  <test_depend>ament_lint_auto</test_depend>
  <test_depend>ament_lint_common</test_depend>

  <export>
    <build_type>ament_cmake</build_type>
  </export>
</package>
```

Comment: Why does your code use the filename "conversions.h" rather than "conversion.h"? If that does not resolve the issue, please edit your post to tell us which exact O.S. are you using.

Comment: Apologies, I miss-typed when I said conversion.h, the file and the include should be conversions.h, I've edited it to include the details of my OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure of the solution to my problem, but I resolved it.
The following is my current source code, CMakeList.txt and package.xml.

octomap_publisher_node.cpp

```
#include <rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp>
#include <octomap/octomap.h>
#include <octomap_msgs/conversions.h>
#include <octomap_msgs/msg/octomap.hpp>
#include <iostream>

class OctomapPublisher : public rclcpp::Node
{
public:
    OctomapPublisher(const std::string& octree_file)
        : Node("octomap_publisher"), octree_file_(octree_file)
    {
        publisher_ = this->create_publisher<octomap_msgs::msg::Octomap>("octomap", 10);
        timer_ = this->create_wall_timer(
            std::chrono::milliseconds(500),
            std::bind(&OctomapPublisher::publishOctomap, this));
    }

private:
    void publishOctomap()
    {
        octomap::OcTree* tree = nullptr;

        // Load the octree from the OT file
        tree = dynamic_cast<octomap::OcTree*>(octomap::AbstractOcTree::read(octree_file_));
        if (!tree) {
            RCLCPP_ERROR(this->get_logger(), "Failed to read octree from file");
            return;
        }

        // Convert the octree to a message
        octomap_msgs::msg::Octomap msg;
        octomap_msgs::binaryMapToMsg(*tree, msg);
        msg.header.frame_id = "map";
        msg.header.stamp = this->now();
        
        // Publish the message
        publisher_->publish(msg);

        delete tree; // Clean up
    }

    std::string octree_file_;
    rclcpp::Publisher<octomap_msgs::msg::Octomap>::SharedPtr publisher_;
    rclcpp::TimerBase::SharedPtr timer_;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    rclcpp::init(argc, argv);

    if (argc < 2) {
        std::cerr << "Usage: octomap_publisher <octree_file.ot>" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    auto octomap_publisher = std::make_shared<OctomapPublisher>(argv[1]);
    rclcpp::spin(octomap_publisher);

    rclcpp::shutdown();
    return 0;
}
```

CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(octomap_publisher)

# Default to C99
if(NOT CMAKE_C_STANDARD)
  set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
endif()

# Default to C++14
if(NOT CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
endif()


if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

# Find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
find_package(octomap REQUIRED)
find_package(octomap_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(octomap_server REQUIRED)

# Include C++ libraries
include_directories(
  include
)

# Declare a C++ executable
add_executable(octomap_publisher_node src/octomap_publisher_node.cpp)


ament_target_dependencies(octomap_publisher_node
  rclcpp
  octomap
  octomap_msgs
  octomap_server
  )
  
# Specify libraries to link a library or executable target against
target_link_libraries(octomap_publisher_node
  ${OCTOMAP_LIBRARIES}
)

# Specify libraries to link a

# Install targets
install(TARGETS
  octomap_publisher_node
  DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME}
)
ament_package()
```

package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://download.ros.org/schema/package_format3.xsd" schematypens="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"?>
<package format="3">
  <name>octomap_publisher</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>TODO: Package description</description>
  <maintainer email="ajifoster3@gmail.com">ajifoster3</maintainer>
  <license>TODO: License declaration</license>

  <buildtool_depend>ament_cmake_auto</buildtool_depend>

  <depend>octomap_msgs</depend>
  <depend>octomap</depend>
  <depend>rclcpp</depend>
  <depend>octomap_server</depend>
  
  <test_depend>ament_lint_auto</test_depend>
  <test_depend>ament_lint_common</test_depend>

  <export>
    <build_type>ament_cmake</build_type>
  </export>
</package>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this tutorial, your CMakeLists.txt file needs to specify that the compiler use version 14 of the c++ standard.

https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Writing-A-Simple-Cpp-Publisher-And-Subscriber.html

```
# Default to C++14
if(NOT CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
endif()
```

Comment: This isn't my issue and I can "colcon build" the simple publishers and subscribers without specifying c++14 :(